# cannot set PATH on .profile

Tags: macos, zsh

I am new to the MAC OSX and am trying to set my `PATH` variable. In my `.profile` I have the following code

```
# .profile

echo "hello world"

export PATH=/foo:$PATH
```

When I launch the terminal, I get:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 23 20:35:54 on ttys000
hello world
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

The file is executed since I see the echo message. However, the $PATH variable does not change at all. Why is that?

EDIT

I've tried to echo out the `PATH` variable from the script, as follows:

```
# .profile

echo "hello world"

export PATH=/foo:$PATH
echo $PATH
```

Which gives me:

```
Last login: Thu Oct 23 20:53:14 on ttys000
hello world
/foo:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
➜  ~  echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
➜  ~
```

I don't understand this behavior. The `PATH` variable is modified while the `.profile` script is being executed, but resets to the default afterwards. Is that by design or am I doing something wrong here?

Any help would be very appreciated.

EDIT:

Thanks to the comments. I could find the root of the problem: Since I am using `zsh`, there's also a `.zshrc` file which is executed after the `.profile`.

Comment: Are you resetting PATH variable again somewhere else (~/.bash_profile etc)? Run ". .profile" (it means to source it in the current shell) where your .profile exists and then run "echo $PATH" and see what value PATH has. Make sure any other profile file (.bash_profile or similar) is NOT setting your PATH variable to something else (what you're seeing for the final PATH echo).

Comment: Some other file is being sourced at some point, as you do not have a default `bash` prompt. Wherever `PS1` is being set, it's a good bet that `PATH` is being modified there as well. Try running `set -x` before you execute  `. .profile`, then examine the output for a line like `. some-file` or `source some-file`.

Comment: I don't have a ~/bash_profile. I've made the .profile executable and get the same results. While the script runs, the PATH variable is modified, but after the script ends, the PATH has the old value.

Comment: I am using the zsh shell

Comment: Surely you should be setting the path in your `~/.zshrc` file.

Comment: The solution is very simple, put `export PATH=/foo:$PATH` at **very end** of your ~/.zshrc file.